# Preencher um datatable a partir de um txt

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Tenho um datareader escrevendo diretamente no arquivo de texto,

```
int count = dataReader.FieldCount;
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(dataReader.GetValue(i));
                    }
                }
            } while (dataReader.NextResult());
```

Esse é o fruto desse código,

```
1--------------------------------------------Esse cara é a primeira coluna, Codigo Fabricante

FABRICANTE GENERICO----------Esse cara é a segunda coluna, Fabricante

BLOCO GENERICO-------------------Esse cara é a terceira coluna, Bloco

EMAIL GENERICO---------------------Esse cara é a quarta coluna, Email

OUTRO CODIGO DE FAB2

OUTRO FABR. GEN2

OUTRO BLO. GEN2

OUTRO EMAIL GEN2

OUTRO CODIGO DE FAB3

OUTRO FABR. GEN3

OUTRO BLO. GEN3

OUTRO EMAIL GEN3
```

...
Só que na forma que obtive os dados, não consigo estrutura-los em um datatable, por não ter recebido o nome de coluna,
mas sei qual que é e quantidade. Poderia fazer uma inserção no datatable com as colunas estáticas? Tipo,

Pseudocódigo;

```
ENQUANTO ((LINHA = DATATABLE.PROXIMALINHA()) OU != NULO)
        {
    COLUNA 0 = Codigo...; 
    COLUNA 1 = Fabri...;
    COLUNA 2 = Bloco...;
    COLUNA 3 = Email...;
    SE(HOUVERLINHA){
        PARA(I=0;ENQUANTO I <= I+4; I++){
        DATATABLE.COLUNA(I).LINHA = LELINHAARQUIVO();       
        }   
        I+=4;           
    }
```

Ou então melhor forma?

Comment: Tenta ver isto, penso que é o que necessitas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860101/how-to-read-text-file-to-datatable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Oi Joana, valeu de verdade, me ajudou bastante a encontrar uma solução !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se você quer popular um `DataTable`, não deveria está utilizando um `DataReader`, mas sim um `DataAdapter`.:

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(minhaConsulta, customerConnection);
var dataSet = new DataSet();  
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Tabela");
var dataTable = customerOrders.Tables["Tabela"];
```

**EDIT**

**PivotGrid - DevExpress**

Quanto ao `PivotGrid` da `DevExpress`, não posso te ajudar muito, mas segundo eles, o ideal para o seu cenário é utilizar [`Database Server Mode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/18010/Controls-and-Libraries/Pivot-Grid/Binding-to-Data/Database-Server-Mode), seja utilizando um `EntityServerModeDataSource` ou `LinqServerModeDataSource` como `DataSource`. No site da DevExpress tem este guia sobre o [`Entity Framework 4.0+ Server Mode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/8601/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Binding-to-Data/Server-Mode/Entity-Framework-4-0-Server-Mode)

**Paginação Sql Server**

Quanto a paginação, você tem duas opções, utilizar o novo `OFFSET FETCH`, que está disponível desde o `SQL Server 2012`, ou utilizar o `ROW_NUMBER`, este está disponível desde o `SQL Server 2005`

**OFFSET FETCH**

```
DECLARE @page as int
DECLARE @pageSize as int

SET @page = 10
SET @pageSize = 20

SELECT TabelaId, Coluna1, Coluna2, ..., ColunaN
FROM Tabela 
ORDER BY TabelaId -- Ou Qual quer outro critério de ordenação 
OFFSET (@page * @pageSize) ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

No exemplo acima, o `OFFSET` irá ignorar os 200 primeiros registros, enquanto o `FETCH` irá ler apenas os próximos 20 registros. Desta forma será retornado apenas os registros de numero 201 à 220.

**ROW_NUMBER**

```
DECLARE @page as int
DECLARE @pageSize as int

SET @page = 10
SET @pageSize = 20

WITH CTE_Page AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TabelaId) AS Ordem, -- Ou Qual quer outro critério de ordenação 
        *
    FROM Tabela 
)

SELECT TabelaId, Coluna1, Coluna2, ..., ColunaN
FROM CTE_Page 
WHERE Ordem BETWEEN (@page * @pageSize + 1) AND (@page * @pageSize + @pageSize)
```

O `ROW_NUMBER` irá criar uma numerar os registros sequencialmente se baseando no critério de ordenação. O `WHERE` irá filtrar os registros para retornar apenas os de ordem entre 201 e 220.

**Leitura de Arquivo**

Neste caso é interessante criar um arquivo com posição fixa, para se possível se buscar um registro por uma linha especifica.

No exemplo abaixo estou a utilizar o pacote [`FlatFile.FixedLength.Attributes`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlatFile.FixedLength.Attributes/).

**MyClass**

```
using FlatFile.FixedLength;
using FlatFile.FixedLength.Attributes;

[FixedLengthFile]
public class MyClass
{
    [FixedLengthField(1, 5, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Right)]
    public int Indice { get; set; }
    [FixedLengthField(1, 50, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Left)]
    public Guid Campo01 { get; set; }
    [FixedLengthField(2, 50, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Left)]
    public Guid Campo02 { get; set; }
    [FixedLengthField(3, 50, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Left)]
    public Guid Campo03 { get; set; }
    [FixedLengthField(4, 50, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Left)]
    public Guid Campo04 { get; set; }
    [FixedLengthField(5, 50, PaddingChar = ' ', Padding = Padding.Left)]
    public Guid Campo05 { get; set; }
}
```

**Escrevendo um Arquivo**

```
var factory = new FixedLengthFileEngineFactory();
var flatFile = factory.GetEngine<MyClass>();
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\Temp\Registros.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        var registro = new MyClass();
        registro.Indice = i;
        registro.Campo01 = Guid.NewGuid();
        registro.Campo02 = Guid.NewGuid();
        registro.Campo03 = Guid.NewGuid();
        registro.Campo04 = Guid.NewGuid();
        registro.Campo05 = Guid.NewGuid();
        flatFile.Write<MyClass>(stream, new List<MyClass> { registro });
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima estou tentando simular o comportamento do `DataReader`, você você escreverá registro por registro no arquivo.

**Lendo do Arquivo**

```
var factory = new FixedLengthFileEngineFactory();
var flatFile = factory.GetEngine<MyClass>();

var lineSize = 257;
var page = 10;
var pageSize = 20;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\Temp\Registros.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    var binary = new byte[pageSize * lineSize];
    var inicio = lineSize * (page * pageSize);
    stream.Seek((long)inicio, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read(binary, 0, binary.Length);
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream(binary))
    {
        var registros = flatFile.Read<MyClass>(memory).ToList();
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, foram lidos apenas os registros do numero 201 ao 220.

Comment: Opa Tobias, já estou saindo de um dataset. Para ser mais específico, devido da uma quantidade grosseira de dados chegando a casa dos bilhões, isso é quase impossivel de se carregar na memória levando em consideração que não tenho um analysis service, e o dataset tem esse problema de carregar na memória e estourar. No caso eu estou utilizando um reader que grava linha a linha em texto para tirar essa carga e depois populo o table pra passar pro datasource do grid. De qualquer forma agradeço a opinião

Comment: Acredito que o DataGrid só exiba alguns registros por vez, então é interessante que você pagine a sua consulta.

Comment: Utilizo um outro tipo de grid, sendo direto, o PivotGrid do DevExpress, e a paginação da forma que conheço, seria com `Select top*` e ele carregaria tudo. o que geralmente demora quase 1 hora pra exibir só os selecionados.

Comment: @NardierBarbosa realizei alguma considerações.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var columns = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
   columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
}
```

outro exemplo

```
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```

Comment: Oi Andreia, agradeço bastante a contribuição. Consegui uma solução ideal no momento, mas vou testar a sua posteriormente com o feedback. Vou colocar uma solução na resposta ...

Answer (score 0):

A solução ficou dessa forma.

```
public DataTable ConverteArquivoTextoParaDataTable(string ArquivoTxt)
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("Coluna1", typeof(String));          
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Coluna2", typeof(String));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Coluna3", typeof(String));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Coluna4", typeof(String));


        string[] totalLinhas = File.ReadAllLines(ArquivoTxt);
        int colunaIndex = 0;
        DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        foreach (string qtdLinhas in totalLinhas )
        {
            dr[colunaIndex] = qtdLinhas ;
            if (colunaIndex == 3)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                colunaIndex = 0;
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                GRIDGENERICO.DataSource = dataTable;
                GRIDGENERICO.DataMember = 
                dataTable.TableName.ToString();
                GRIDGENERICO.Refresh();

                }));
            }
            else
            {
                colunaIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Inseri as colunas na mão.
Li a quantidade de linhas do arquivo de texto.
Considerei utilizar os índices. E o invoke é devido thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

Qual a sua versão do SQL Server? Dependendo podemos utilizar o ROWNUMBER ou o OFFSET FETCH. E quanto ao PivotGrid, pode utilizar o [Virtual Scroll](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/17833/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Pivot-Grid/Layout/Paging-and-Scrolling/Virtual-Scrolling)

Comment: SqlServer 2014.